# C++ Polymorphic Class Variables and Functions

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

I'm creating a game in C++, with all object classes stemming from one base class, `Instance`, and they are all listed into a `vector`. I must be able to access both variables and functions from the pointers in the vector. Here's my code for activating each update method of each instance:

```
for (double j = 1000; j >= -1000; j -= 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < instances.size(); i += 1) {
        if (instances[i]->depth == j) {
            instances[i]->update();
        }
    }
}
```

I can access the functions and execute them, and the individual instances can access their own functions, but I cannot access the instances through `instances[i]->whatevervariable`, and it seems to take the variable's value from the base class. Using `dynamic_casts` would not help, as I'm trying to make the game very flexible. So how can I set the

```
std::vector<Instances*> instances;
```

so it allows me to access both variables and functions through `instances[i]->`?

Classes:

```
class Instance {
    public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double depth;

    virtual void update() { };
};
class Ball : public Instance {
    public:
    double x;
    double y;
    double depth;

    void update() {
        x += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ball is not inheriting from instance

Comment: You don't need to declare the variables in Ball if Ball is inheriting from Instance.  You should be declaring class Ball as a derived class of Instance, though, in its class declaration, IE class Ball : public Instance.

Comment: You might want update to be pure virtual as well.
`virtual void update() = 0;`

Comment: I edited the inheritance on Ball that I forgot.

Comment: You should still remove the duplicate variable declarations from the Ball class.  It will inherit the public variables from Instance.

Comment: I'm suggesting you not to use vector for this scenario, but use **composite pattern** instead. this comment is not related to you question but to your code. more info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redeclare Ball as the following

```
class Ball : public Instance {
    public:
    void update() {
        x += 1;
    }
}
```

By putting the ": public Instance" you are making Ball being a derived class of Instance and have the same public or protected attributes, it will have the depth,x and y ones without declaring them explicitly.

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/112-basic-inheritance-in-c/

Comment: If you look at the code again, I meant to add that but I forgot to.

Comment: It did work, by removing the duplicate variable declarations. Thanks.